# Splicer video rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, splicer

I am using Splicer from Codeplex, but I have difficulty to compile my sample code.

It returns me error because of

```
using (IRenderer renderer = new WindowsMediaRenderer(timeline, outputFile, WindowsMediaProfiles.HighQualityVideo))
```

It returns me " used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable' ". It caused me not be able to compile my program.

Why there's this problem and how to solve this problem? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 8):

`IRenderer` does not implement IDisposable`interface, where the`WindowsMediaRenderer`implements it. to correct the issue in the example replace the`IRenderer`with`WindowsMediaRenderer`:

```
using (WindowsMediaRendererrenderer renderer = new WindowsMediaRenderer(timeline, outputFile, WindowsMediaProfiles.HighQualityVideo))
```

Comment: @williamtio: don't forget to mark this answer as [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it solves your problem so others will know that it helps you.